# How to get message info by ID [Telegram API]

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm writing bot for telegram to gather some stats from group chat. I need to get info about every message (from the beginning of chat). I know how can i do it, but it's a quite bad idea. I can use forwardMessage method, but i need second acc for it and i'm getting timeouted when i'm sending messages too fast (for one hour), so it's a bit long way to collect stats for conversation that has over 2 million messages ;s I tried to set limit on 10 messages per second but i'm still getting timeouted, so idk how it works.
There must be other way to get JUST message info by id without forwarding it ;v I can't find it in API.

Answer (score 2):

There has no API to do this at this time, you can suggest this idea to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport), before them added this feature, I am doing same thing like you.

According to [Bot FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this), Telegram API rate limit 1/s pre chat, and global limit is 30/s.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with Telegram bot api, you can use **ReadHistory** Method of [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto) without the necessity to use forward message method